# woostercollective.com / Responsive Transition not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm wondering about http://www.woostercollective.com

They have some nice responsive transitions that occurs when window size is toggled, seems to be loaded with jQuery - but I can't figure out how their calling & customizing it with each div container. How do you a lot where they go?

Using the loaded jQuery transitions, attaching them to the divs, and defining with media queries in `min-widths`?

**How are they implementing their jQuery responsive transitions?**

Also - kind of interesting, their site doesn't actually respond in mobile (Checked on iOs/andrdoid) Maybe their missing their `viewport meta` or is this just a fancy trend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using the Masonry plugin

```
http://masonry.desandro.com/
```

The transitions are css transitions where the position values are animated.

For example (in webkit):

```
-webkit-transition-property: left;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
```

When the css "left" value changes, the element is told to animate the "left" value over a timeperiod of 1 second, instead of just immediately jumping to that position.